# "GridWorld" for ThinkJava Exercise 5.1

Tags: java, if-statement, gridworld

Newbie completeing thinkJava book and trying to figure out one of the answers to the exercises. It calls for me to download the "GridWorld" files and complete the following steps:

1. Write a method named moveBug that takes a bug as a
   parameter and invokes move. Test your method by calling it from main.
2. Modify moveBug so that it invokes canMove and moves the bug only if
   it can.
3. Modify moveBug so that it takes an integer, n, as a parameter, and
   moves the bug n times (if it can).
4. Modify moveBug so that if the bug can’t move, it invokes turn instead.

*I am stuck on number 3, I can not figure out how to pass n into the "move() method"*

-Please Help I am a newbie

My Code:

```
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
import info.gridworld.actor.Rock;

public class BugRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
        Bug redBug = new Bug();
        world.add(redBug);
        world.add(new Rock());
        world.show();
        moveBug(redBug,5);
        System.out.println(redBug.getLocation());
    }

    public static void moveBug(Bug aBug, int n){
        if(aBug.canMove() == true){
        aBug.move();
        } else {
        aBug.turn();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me @Andreas
My Solution that worked:

```
public static void moveBug(Bug aBug, int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(aBug.canMove())
           {
           aBug.move();
           } else {
           aBug.turn();
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: So with if/else statements inside a method are you not able to pass the value of parameter "n" directly into the if/else ex:"move(n)".....? @Andreas

Comment: You almost got it. Change to `i < n`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you're stuck on number 3:

> 3. Modify moveBug so that it takes an integer, n, as a parameter, and moves the bug n times (if it can).

This means write a loop, looping `n` times, calling `move()` once per iteration, if `canMove()` returns true.

BTW: `if (canMove() == true) {...}` is the long way to say `if (canMove()) {...}`.

And fix the indentation of the `if` statement.

Comment: @Deximus The answer where I help OP get on the right track without handing out the solution to an exercise.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I needed to do @Andreas